# Why do vectors often have 1 dimenision as 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

In textbooks and school, why is it that vectors are often shown to be n x 1 or 1 x n matrices? I have rarely seen other dimensioned matrices representing matrices.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
  \end{bmatrix} is usually a matrix but

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    3 \\
    4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
is usually a vector. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Simplicity of notation. Using a 2x3 matrix allows you to represent 6 quantities with the understanding that there is some sort of "grouping" within those 6 quantities (2 sets of 3 quantities that are in some way "different"). When we work with vectors we are not usually concerned with such an internal grouping. Note, however, that there is nothing stopping you from viewing a 1xn set of scalars as a matrix or as a vector. You must simply make clear the type of mathematical object you are working with. After all, you could represent a 2x2 matrix as a column of 4 quantities, right? but that wouldn't be a very convenient or simple notation.

Answer (score 0):

Beside its application in linear algebra, a (m,n)-matrix is just a table of numbers, i.e a map from $\{1,\dots,m\}\times\{1,\dots,n\}$ into $R$, where $R$ is a ring.

In a vector space, given a basis, a vector can be represented by a column or a line of numbers. So a vector can be represented by a $(n,1)$-matrix or a $(1,n)$-matrix.

But the space $M_{m,n}(R)$ of $(m,n)$-matrices is itself a vector space, so its elements are vectors. Hence the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ 
  \end{bmatrix}$  is also a vector (of the vector space $M_{m,n}(R)$).

Using the basis $\{ E_{i,j} \}$ of $M_{m,n}(R)$, you can write a matrix as a column or a line vector. For instance, the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}$

can be represented as $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is the basis $(E_{1,1},E_{1,2},E_{1,3},E_{2,1},E_{2,2},E_{2,3})$. Note that you note to fix an order on the $E_{i,j}$'s.

What is important is to remember what you are speaking about:
-> elements of a vector space (aka vectors): we use line or column representations
-> linear applications between vectors spaces of finite dimension: we use matrices

Answer (score -1):

Yes, usually column vectors ($1\times n$ matrices) are used for vectors. But vectors are also very commonly regarded as such matrices, e.g. the matrix product $A\cdot v$ is everywhere used.

For another example, we can also build a matrix (of range $1$) by the matrix product $v^Tv$.

So, in many cases it is extremely useful to apply matrix operations for (column and/or row) vectors simply regarding them as matrices.